# Why can ElementTree not parse the copy of an XML-file

Tags: xml, python-3.x

For some reasons I have to replace german umlauts in an XML file.
For this I wrote this small code.
I know that it is better to avoid umlauts and having correct UTF8 coding in the XML, but I have to deal with it...

I Always got errors while parsing the copyied XML, so I used an XML which I can parse without replacing the umlauts from https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-xml-elementtree.

This XML worked (so it seems to be a valid XML), but I am not able to parse the copyied XML, even if there is no replacement.
I use xdiff to find any differences between the two file, but it seems, that both files are the same.
Can anybody tell me whats wrong here? I think it has to do with the encoding, but I am not really sure...

```
import os
import ansa
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def main():

    File ='source.xml'
    Copy ='source_cpy.xml'
    Out = open(Copy,'w',encoding = 'UTF-8')
    with open(File,'r',encoding ='ISO-8859-1') as Input:
        for Line in Input:
            print (Line)
            Newline = Line#.replace(u'ä','ae').replace(u'ü','ue').replace(u'ö','oe')
            Out.write(Newline)
    tree = ET.parse(File)
    print (tree)
    tree = ET.parse(Copy)
    print (tree)
```

The result is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/xmlparsertest.py (Run from Script Editor)", line 21, in

File "/home/xmlparsertest.py (Run from Script Editor)", line 17, in main

File "/python/linux64/lib/python3.3/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1242, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)

File "/python/linux64/lib/python3.3/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1730, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse(source)

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

What I like to have is a solution,that my copyied XML is a valid XML

Comment: It seems that the reason ist that i did not closed the file i just created. Can aanyone explain me why?

Comment: Because of buffering data will not always be written to files right away. I think the author of [this](https://www.djangospin.com/python-file-buffering/) article at djangospin does a good job of explaining it.